# Historical flight stats free of charge

Tags: british-airways, flight-status

Its not duplicate. Where can i find old fligh status free of charge? I need to check BA 677 flight on 31 July 2016. Flightstats and flightAware are with payment.

Comment: Please use the existing question. Just because it doesn't have an answer doesn't mean you should ask a duplicate. Thank you.

Comment: I am asking for the source which is free of charge. In given answer, there are websites with the payment. And i cannot add comment to this existing question.